# What to do when logcat shows error in non-existent lines in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, logcat

I have edited the `NullPointerException` present in `MainActivity` and have exported (cut, copy and paste)them into another class. But my Logcat shows an error in `MainActivity`.
After modifying for `NullPointerException this is my code:

```java
    if(value!=null && value.length()>0){
      try{
        length = Integer.parseInt(value);

      }
      catch (NullPointerException e){
        length=0;
      }
    }
```

My logcat shows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable 
        android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.caddrawingtool.MainActivity.drawline(MainActivity.java:114)
        at com.example.caddrawingtool.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:57)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:4137)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:384)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:228)
      androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:109)
```

when my `MainActivity` has only 109 lines. I am confused.

Comment: Are you building with R8/ProGuard enabled (`minifyEnabled true`)? If so, maybe try turning that off and rebuild. If not, maybe try cleaning and doing a full rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Simple once click on Build (On top) and then look for clean project